# Are there muggle ghosts in the Wizarding World?

Tags: harry-potter

Are the ghosts in the Harry Potter universe limited to magic users?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No there are no muggle ghosts in the wizarding world, because yes ghosts are limited to magic users.

> Nearly Headless Nick hesitated, then said, “**Not everyone can come back as a ghost**.”
>
> “What d’you mean?” said Harry quickly.
>
> “Only… **only wizards.**”

Comment: Sigh. I thought, perhaps, Peeves was a former tennis pro.

Comment: @MajorStackings Alas that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: @MajorStackings - Ah, but Peeves is a poltergeist, which is not a ghost. I will now go to my grave believing that Peeves is a tennis pro. It's canon! :)

Comment: @Slytherincess Poltergeists are ghosts...

Comment: **NominSim** is totally correct. From *Tales of Beedle the Bard*: *Ghosts are transparent, moving, talking and thinking versions of **wizards and witches** who wished, for whatever reason, to remain on earth.* (page 79, Bloomsbury edition) :)

Comment: @NominSim Not in the Harry Potter universe.

Comment: @NominSim - Technically not. A Poltergeist, although it means "noisy ghost" in German, is considered more of an manifestation of negative energy, that tends to attach itself to an individual person rather than a place (such as Hogwarts). Yes, I realize Peeves doesn't fit this mold, but I'm just addressing the meaning of the word. Since you're okay with the Wiki, here is the link to [Poltergeist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poltergeist). :)

Comment: @Slytherincess I suppose I should have said "can be" ghosts. They aren't always (or even usually) mutually distinguishable.

Comment: @NominSim - I'm comfortable with my explanation of a poltergeist, but it doesn't surprise me that people have different ideas about what constitutes one. :)

Comment: Peeves is not a ghost and was never alive according to Word of God.  But it's true that some stories outside Harry Potter do have poltergeists that are definitely the ghost of a human that was once alive.  An example is the short story “Legal Rites” by Isaac Asimov and Fred Pohl.

Comment: Interesting then that, in "The Deathday Party" chapter of book 2, a group of ghosts identified as 'nuns' are depicted!

Comment: @NKCampbell Don't forget the Fat Friar (who was, indeed, a friar; witches and wizards don't seem to have any trouble being religious, despite the historic attitudes of religious Muggles towards magic).